# Freeform window animation issue while toggle to fullscreen mode in Android R

Tags: android, freeform

On Android R Pixel device Freeform window has below problem while animating when touched the maximum button:
The freeform window's content is covered by the icons on Launcher !

This is caused by freeform window animation leash is under Launcher's animation leash .

Does anyone had found this same issue and any resolutions ?

Freeform window animates well after touched the maximum button